# Getting Count Of Rows In DataTable With Variable

Tags: c#, datatable

I am wanting to get a count of rows in my DataTable that meet specific criteria.  My issue (I think) is that I am trying to use a column name as part of the `Select` statement.  So this is what I have:

```
string twodigmonth = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM");
DataRow[] Test= dataTable1.Select(" " + dateasstring.Split('/')[0] + " = " + "'" + twodigmonth + "'");
```

I get a compile error of:

> The name dateasstring does not exist in the current context.

But I have a column in my datatable that is string data type named this.

```
DataTable dataTable1 = new DataTable();
dataTable1.Columns.Add("dateasstring", typeof(string));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of fiddling around with the odd and old `DataTable.Select` syntax, why don't you use the modern and much more powerful LINQ?

```
int currentMonth = DateTime.Today.Month;
int matchingRows = dataTable1.AsEnumerable()
 .Count(r => DateTime.Parse(r.Field<string>("dateasstring")).Month == currentMonth);
```

I would store the `dateasstring` as real `DateTime`, then you don't need to parse it every time.

Comment: That is much cleaner!  I will have to google LINQ examples on how to achieve this.  I see one potential issue tho, in my sample code I am extracting only the first two digits of the full date from my datatable.  in your example, is that taking the full date from the datatable or only the first two digits?

Comment: @HotTomales: why you store the date as string in the DataTable?

Comment: As crazy as it sounds that is how I am being requested to store it.

Comment: @HotTomales: well, that's a terrible way to store it. But you could use above approach. Note that it will also count rows which are from last year.

Comment: I whole-heartedly agree.  These people do not understand DataBase Design (I am not claiming to, just have a better idea than they do).  They have a master tabtle that houses all the data, then they create a view for each year.  With that being said checking the year is not an issue.